# Web service to display products

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, web-services, performance

I'm building a small webshop in .net. The webshop solution will contain several "webshops" that use the same server.

My question is this: when I have a product menu and product listing, will there be any performance problems with using jQuery Ajax calls to get the selected product(s)?

There will be many calls to the same web service and the web service will get the product data from a SQL Server database and return a xml file. The hardware and server itself will not be a bottleneck.

Thanks for any feedback on this!

Best Regards
Marthin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there won't be. Whether you will do this with ajax, or with a normal request, the load on the server will be the same.